# Google Drive API - upload and export file

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I need to upload a file through Google Drive, and then export it as different format. For example upload DOCX and export it to PDF. I've been following the REST quickstart and the upload files guides. After executing code, I get error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception,  "message":
>   "Insufficient Permission"

It's problem with permissions, but I don't know how to fix it.
Here's the code I use:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Sofia');

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Drive API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/drive-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/drive-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY)
));
//i've tried to change the scope to ::DRIVE, but still get the same error

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 10,
  'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
  print "No files found.\n";
} else {
  print "Files:\n";
  foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
    printf("%s  FILE_ID(%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
  }
}


//The error I get is in this block:

$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
  'name' => 'photo.jpg'));
$content = file_get_contents('photo.jpg');
$file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
  'data' => $content,
  'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
  'uploadType' => 'multipart',
  'fields' => 'id'));
printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that the code works up untill the last block, it lists the files successfully, and then on the last 10 rows throws the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the thing working. I think there was something with the definition of the scopes. BTW I found some examples which were very helpfull [HERE](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples)
The working code is:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Sofia');
include_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
include_once "templates/base.php";
echo pageHeader("File Upload - Uploading a simple file");
/*************************************************
 * Ensure you've downloaded your oauth credentials
 ************************************************/
if (!$oauth_credentials = getOAuthCredentialsFile()) {
  echo missingOAuth2CredentialsWarning();
  return;
}
/************************************************
 * The redirect URI is to the current page, e.g:
 * http://localhost:8080/simple-file-upload.php
 ************************************************/
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($oauth_credentials);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
// add "?logout" to the URL to remove a token from the session
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
}
/************************************************
 * If we have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow,
 * we need to exchange that with the
 * Google_Client::fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode()
 * function. We store the resultant access token
 * bundle in the session, and redirect to ourself.
 ************************************************/
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
  $client->setAccessToken($token);
  // store in the session also
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $token;
  // redirect back to the example
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
// set the access token as part of the client
if (!empty($_SESSION['upload_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
/************************************************
 * If we're signed in then lets try to upload our
 * file. For larger files, see fileupload.php.
 ************************************************/
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $client->getAccessToken()) {

// CREATE A NEW FILE
  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'sample',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation'
  ));
  $pptx = file_get_contents("sample.docx"); // read power point pptx file
  //declare opts params
  $optParams = array(
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'data' => $pptx,
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
  );
  //import pptx file as a Google Slide presentation
  $createdFile = $service->files->create($file, $optParams);
  //print google slides id
  //print "File id: ".$createdFile->id;

  $optParams2 = array(
    'fileId' => $createdFile->id,
    'mimeType' => 'application/pdf'
  );


  $response = $service->files->export($createdFile->id, 'application/pdf', array(
  'alt' => 'media' ));
//print_r($response);
  $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
///rint_r($content);

$data = $content;
file_put_contents('test_ppt.pdf',$data);

}
?>

<div class="box">
<?php if (isset($authUrl)): ?>
  <div class="request">
    <a class='login' href='<?= $authUrl ?>'>Connect Me!</a>
  </div>
<?php elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'): ?>
  <div class="shortened">
    <p>Your call was successful! Check your drive for the following files:</p>
    <ul>


    </ul>
  </div>
<?php else: ?>
  <form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Click here to upload two small (1MB) test files" />
  </form>
<?php endif ?>
</div>

<?= pageFooter(__FILE__) ?>
```

If you want to convert to other formats, just change the Mime types, following the references: [HERE](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types) and [HERE](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)

Answer (score 2):

Scopes define the scope of access that you request of a user.  You have authenticated your code with the following permissions.

> Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY

Which gives you read only access.  The following is a list of [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#drivev3) available to the Google drive api.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive  View and manage the files in your Google Drive
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata  View and manage its own configuration data in your Google Drive
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata View and manage metadata of files in your Google Drive
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly    View metadata for files in your Google Drive
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly  View the photos, videos and albums in your Google Photos
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly View the files in your Google Drive
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts  Modify your Google Apps Script scripts' behavior

I would probably go with the first one `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`.  I am only guessing here but for PHP it may be something like `Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE`

Comment: I've changed the scope to  `::DRIVE`, but the same error still appears

Comment: After you change the scope, you also need to de-authorize your app and go through the auth flow again. Also, use Drive.File scope, not Drive because you are encouraged to only request the minimum necessary scope, and Drive.File will suffice.